# Embed print link with in html email?

Tags: html, email, printing, html-email, email-client

i am trying to embed a print link with in an html email blast.

i have tried following code but it does not work.

```
<a href="javascript:window.print();">
<img src="reward_08.gif" border="0"  width="71" height="52" alt="PRINT">
</a>
```

Above code works fine when i do it within a webpage.

Any suggestions?

Comment: E-Mails generally don't support JavaScript. Most E-Mail clients will have a "Print" button though, no?

Comment: Yes Email client will have a print button. but can we achieve this functionality without using javascript. It is one of the functionality my office wants me to add in email.

Comment: Not really. The only workaround I can think of is linking to a web page, and having a print button on *that*

Comment: Short of instructing the user to "Press CTRL + P to print the contents of this message", Pekka's web page solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the comments, since email clients don't generally support javascript. You can have a button/text link to an external page that is a copy of the email and change the `<body>` tag to this

```
<body onload="window.print()">
```