# HTML Printable ticket in email

Tags: html, reporting, html-email

Hey I have to generate some certificates and tickets dynamically and send them in an email. Also I want them to get printed from email (just like a pdf) through a print option provided in mail. I don't want to open an external window. The print should directly come to the printer on clicking the print option in email. This print option will be different from the default Print Email option provided by the Gmail/Yahoo mailers.

Please guide me which technology should be used here and how can I sent an HTML dynamically generated in email.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176806/embed-print-link-with-in-html-email

Comment: Hey But in first place how would I create an email with HTML content in it

Answer (score 0):

I have finally got the Solution. HTML code needs to be embedded in the mail client using source option. Thanks for helping guys.

Also we can't add any script to the mail, so only HTML and inlince CSS is supported.