# window.print() is removed in the Email Template

Tags: javascript, html, email

I am working on a HTML template that is being sent to multiple email clients like Outlook, Gmail, Yahoo, etc. 
In that I have a *Print* method in the footer.

This *print* functionality works perfectly, when tested in different browsers, but the code gets removed when sent to the email clients, thus preventing the Print functionality.

The snippet is as follows (**Expected**):

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="window.print(); return false;">
  Print
</a>
```

**Actual** in email clients:

```
<a>
  Print
</a>
```

I have added `href="javascript:"` for touch based devices to access the Print function.

I have also tried by attaching a `class` and invoking a `click` event using the `script` tag, but the script tag too gets removed.

So, how should I make Print to be executed for the email clients?

**Edit 1:**
I cannot link to any external page as pointed out duplicate in this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176806/embed-print-link-with-in-html-email).

Comment: The email clients are removing the script for security reasons. Is there any real need for this option as the email client already has a highly visible print button.

Comment: Yes, the project requires the Print functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed print link with in html email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176806/embed-print-link-with-in-html-email)

Comment: @jackjop, I am not allowed to link to other page.

Comment: @Shashank Just create one page at the server and use some id to get necessary information to fill mail template again and print. Cannot create one page or modify?

Comment: @jackjop, thankx for it, but I am restricted from doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email clients remove every javascript related element because it might create security issues. So I guess you can't.