# Javascript window.print() function not working in my email template

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, printing, html-email

Good day. I want to send invoice to users after purchase. I want the users to be able to print by pressing the print button, not just viewing the mail. I am using mailtrap to test this from my laravel application. When I test the template from my blade files, the print button opens up the print window, but the button does not work in my mailtrap inbox. What could be the cause?
A sample of my Code is shown below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Invoice</title>
    <style>
        @media print {

            .print{
                display: none;
            }

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<table>
    <tr><td colspan="2">Invoice</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>500</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:window.print();" class="print">Print</a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should not work at all, but sadly there are still mail clients that execute JavaScript...

Comment: JavaScript not allowed in email's HTML, but you can have a button/text link to an external page: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16177385/7238282)

Comment: Thanks. But will the invoice be printable in production. For example, if someone is viewing the mail in Gmail or YahooMail?

Comment: Either send the invoice as attachment (pdf) or use a site where customers can view all their orders with the possibility to save the invoice (pdf) or to just print it.

Comment: Thanks. Will implement that.

Comment: @Andreas why not put what you have written in an answer? It is the way to go.

Comment: @Nathan Because "send a pdf" is not an answer. It's just an advice.

Answer (score 0):

try put function after  tage.and put this instruction below
<input type="button" value="Print"onclick="window.print()" />